# Sidebar Wordpress With Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

When in responsive website the sidebar moves to the footer of the page but the background-color won't fix the size of it, as the print screen.

http://i61.tinypic.com/v8hhkj.gif

What could I do here?

The website: http://bloganacastro.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set width: 100% for the sidebar for proper display in responsive..

```
@media (max-width:  768px) {
 .sidebar.col-md-4 {
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set width: 30% for the sidebar, which makes the background to shrink.
Let the browser calculate the width.

```
@media (max-width:  768px) {
 .sidebar.col-md-4 {
   width: auto;
 }
}
```